# nginx 1.4.4 + https + chunk encoding

Tags: node.js, nginx, https, chunked-encoding

I have a nginx server working as a proxy for a nodejs app displaying chunked data. Everything works perfectly over http but when i try to use https the chunk encoding seems to not work. I know nginx support http chuck encoding since version 1.3.9 but can't find any info regarding https.
Headers sent:

```
'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
            'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
            'Connection': 'Transfer-Encoding'
```

Any advice?
Thanks.

Fixed it adding this parameter

```
proxy_buffering off;
```